# Wahhabism vs extremists why does the theology seem so close?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, sects

I used to say terrorists don’t follow Islam by definition since killing and aggression is clearly against the religion. Learning more about Wahhabi-ism seems to go against this. Please tell me some aspects of what terrorists say and believe that is different from Wahhabi-ism. The more numerous the better because I used to be happy to see another Muslim (beard or hijab) but now think more of the hate terrorists spew out than the love I have for my religious brothers and sisters.

---

I’m asking this due to the impressions I have from friends, family, media, and unfortunately some imams. The thing I want is to highlight the differences because it is not so direct, but some commentators what to know what I think is Wahhabi-ism. That’s why I’m adding this, but I am planning to delete these points after an answer is given because it is too confrontational.

---

Is it true that a man should be killed after going without praying for 3 days or more? Is it true that a man should be killed if they leave the religion? Is it true that women and men must be separated at every level of the society? Is it true that women are viewed to be any different from men in intellect, capabilities like driving or working, and so on? Is it true that sharia law is a legal system of government?

---

I think that for the points I’ve added it’s likely that they are not a part of Wahhabism. I'd love to hear that’s true.

Comment: Oh! You're asking if someone of us is a friend of the ISIS to present what exactly are their notions of 'Islam'. Gotcha!

Comment: @azam Haha, no gotcha here :)

Comment: The takfiri groups like al-Qaida and the "Islamic" State are off-shoots of Wahhabism and were set up by factions of the Wahhabi/Saudi establishment. So obviously they have the same beliefs.

Comment: Perhaps you should first describe the "learning about Wahabism" that was enlightening for you? As for the relation: terrorists believe in God, I believe in God, and maybe you too - does that imply a linkage?

Comment: @Shoaib Well I thinking your hitting the reason for my question on the head. I dont know about Whabbism, but I dont have an impression. I even had to goggle the spelling of its name, and per your spelling Ive got it wrong. Thats why Im asking because I hope that Im wrong about the parallelism. Let me add to the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (a) it's a multi-question question and (b) because it's confrontational and likely to be poorly received.